# How to keep the remove the second column from a .csv file and save the rest of the file to a .txt file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file with two columns, the `id` column contains ids and the `score` column contains a score of the individual, the original .csv file looks something like below:

```
import pandas as pd
record = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1234567891011', '1234567891012', '1234567891013'],
                     'score': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]})
```

I want to define my function to remove the `score` column and then save the `id` column in a format that the ids will not become something like 1.2345e+12, the result should be something like:

```
1234567891011
1234567891012
1234567891013
...
```

so I tried to define my function using the code below:

```
def get_id(fname):
    '''Get id from fname and save it into .txt file'''

    # read in fname as pandas.dataframe
    df = pd.read_csv('fname', header = None, skiprows = 1) 

    # remove score column
    df.drop(df.columns[1], axis = 1, inplace = True)

    # transform the ids from int to str
    df = df.astype(str)

    # save df as .txt
    df.to_csv('fname_txt', header = None, index = None, sep = '\n', mode = 'a')
    return
```

When I test the function above, it gave me an empty .txt file. I know I missed something in the function, but I can't figure out what I miss. Is there a better to do this? Also, is there a way I could save the name of the .txt file the same as the name of the .csv file?

Many Thanks!

Comment: make sure to specify the file type: `df.to_csv(f'{fname}.txt', . . . )` If you are using python 3.6 or greater then use f-strings to name the file the same as `fname`

Comment: This seems to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You don't use `fname` argument. Isn't it supposed to be:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fname, header = None, skiprows = 1)
```

And saving something like this:

```
df.to_csv(f"{fname}_txt.txt", header = None, index = None, sep = '\n', mode = 'a')
```